# incrementing a counter once when within a range

Tags: java, range, increment

I have a program that grabs a file containing boolean values, and I'm counting the number of false values until it reaches a true value. Then, when it encounters another false value it counts them again.  I have a lower threshold and a higher threshold for the number of false values, and I need to increment a counter only once when within this range. This is not a homework assignment, by the way.

```
private static int readBooleanValues(File textFile, int higher, int lower) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (textFile);
    int counter = 0;
    int secondaryCounter = 0;
    while ( scanner.hasNext() ) {
        String value = scanner.next();
        if ( value.equalsIgnoreCase("false") ) {
            counter++;
            if ( counter >= lower && counter <= higher ) {
                secondaryCounter++;
            }
        } else if ( value.equalsIgnoreCase("true") ) {
            counter = 0;
        }    
    }
    return secondaryCounter;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Nice question, but it's unclear what you're asking.  Can you clarify?  Is your code not working?

Comment: Do you want that secondaryCounter counts only once?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but change the `else if` in just `else` because you don't have to check for `true` if it has been checked for `false` before already.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do what @WonderWorld suggested, and also replace

```
if ( counter >= lower && counter <= higher ) {
    secondaryCounter++;
}
```

by

```
if (counter == lower)
    secondaryCounter++;
if (counter == higher+1)
    secondaryCounter--;
```

This increments `secondaryCounter` only once, when it first enters the range. If it later turns out that the string of `false` values is too long (when `counter` reaches `higher+1`), the value of `secondaryCounter` is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
 if ( counter >= lower && counter <= higher ) {
                secondaryCounter++;
            }
```

to

```
if ( counter >= lower) {
                secondaryCounter++;counter=0;
            }
```

Now your range will not be in reach, `counter` will stay zero while `Scanner` is reading true values, and you can start again. Although if having too many `false` values invalidates the count, you will need to take further action.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could place the secondaryCounter in the true part:

```
if ( value.equalsIgnoreCase("false") ) {
            counter++;
            }
        } else if ( value.equalsIgnoreCase("true") ) {
       if ( counter >= lower && counter <= higher ) {
                secondaryCounter++;
        } 
           counter = 0;
```